# How do I reduce the download size of my universal iOS app made in Unity to less than 100MB?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I've been making an iOS game (Head of State) since the beginning of the year. I launched it with ARMv64 architecture and the download size was just over 30MB. I want to publish an update with Universal architecture and some more content but now I'm struggling to get the download size under Apple's 100MB limit for downloading over cellular networks.

I know universal architecture will nearly double the size of the build, and adding more images also increased it. Before optimising the unity build size was 70MB and the Apple download size was 108MB. So, only 8MB to cut down I thought. But, after I tried reducing the file size by compressing textures and audio (following [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html) guide for reducing file size), the unity size was down to 53MB, but the Apple download size was only down to 102MB...

I can't compress the audio or images more without it becoming very noticeable in game, and I don't understand how I can have cut the Unity build size by 17MB, but the Apple download size by only 6MB. I would love for someone to explain this to me and give me some tips for how to reduce the Apple download size that extra bit to get under 100MB.

[Here are my Unity build settings](https://puu.sh/rPATP/2fce5fefe6.png)

I'm using Unity 5.4.1f1 and Xcode 8.0

Comment: are you stripping the engine code at all?

Comment: I'm using IL2CPP scripting backend, so as I understand it the equivalent of Strip ByteCode is always enabled (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html)

Comment: ah yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in the comments above, I ended up switching to .NET 2.0 subset from .NET 2.0 and this brought the package size down well under 100MB

Answer (score 2):

The default image compression for iOS looks bad but with a custom atlas packing policy you can override the compression quality and make it more bearable.

Have you checked from unity build log what'a taking most of the space?

Also, where are you checking the download size and have you tested that the build actually does not download over cellular? AFAIK the displayed size in app store is some uncompressed version and doesn't need to fit exactly 100MB

Comment: I checked the log and reduced the image and audio sizes quite a bit already. As I say, I took the unity build size down from 70MB to 53MB, but it didn't seem to make a big difference to the projected download size that Apple was telling me.

Comment: I've switched to .NET 2.0 subset from .NET 2.0 though, and this as brought things down to 93MB, so I'll test with that and cross my fingers

Comment: Custom policy needs some work but the compression quality is much better than the default, and for some reason Unity doesn't expose the setting directly in editor. Check the Sprite Packer docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpritePacker.html and the compression quality can be checked through AtlasSettings: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprites.AtlasSettings.html